# Getting equivalent for each loop/stream for below code

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert the piece of code to equivalent stream or for-each loop

```java
for (Studentauditlog st: studentauditloglist) {
    String columnValue = callEntityGetterMethod(st, column);
                 
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(columnValue)) {
        if (response.containsKey(columnValue)) {
            Long count = (response.get(columnValue) == null)? 0L : response.get(columnValue);
                         
            response.put(columnValue, count + 1);
        } else {                     
            response.put(columnValue, 1L);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: I have written above one only but need an equivalent code in JAVA streams

Comment: @TechTravellers what have you tried so far to construct an equivalent code in Java streams? (BTW, this isn't valid code)

Comment: @AndyTurner I am not getting how to call a method from streams

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing code calculates a `response` map where non-blank String columns are keys, and the map values are the frequencies of the keys.

This can be implemented as a sequence of `Stream::map`, `Stream::filter` to get column values, which are grouped using `Collectors.groupingBy` with the `Collectors.counting` as a downstream collector.

See the implementation below:

```java
Map<String, Long> response = studentauditloglist
    .stream() // Stream<Studentauditlog >
    .map(st -> callEntityGetterMethod(st, column))
    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank) // Stream<String>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        cv -> cv, // or Function.identity()
        Collectors.counting()
    ));
```